# Printing a linked list in C using CodeBlocks

Tags: c, linked-list

So I recently took up C and I'm following a simple tutorial online that creates and prints out a linked list. I have followed it step to step and for some reason, the guy in the tutorial is able to print out his list and I'm not. It's driving me nuts. Nothing shows up when I build and run (using CodeBlocks).

He is using some other text editor and maybe a different compiler but I can't for the life of me see how the exact same code can have two different behaviors? Anyone got any ideas? Here's the code:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct List {
    struct Node *head;   
};

void pushList(struct List *linkedList, int value) {
    if (linkedList->head == NULL) { 
        struct Node *newNode;
        newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        newNode->data = value;
        linkedList->head = newNode;
    } else {
        struct Node *tNode = linkedList->head;
        while (tNode->next != NULL) {
            tNode = tNode->next;
        }
        struct Node *newNode;
        newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        newNode->data = value;
        tNode->next = newNode;
    }
}

void printList(struct List *linkedList) {
    struct Node *tNode = linkedList->head;
    while (tNode != NULL) {
        printf("This node has a value of %d\n", tNode->data);
        tNode = tNode->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    struct List newList = { 0 }; //This initializes to null

    pushList(&newList, 200);
    pushList(&newList, 300);
    pushList(&newList, 400);
    pushList(&newList, 500);

    printList(&newList);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Did you `#include` `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`?

Comment: `newNode->data = value;` --> `newNode->data = value;newNode->next = NULL;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to initialize `newNode->next = NULL;`.  `malloc` does not initialize the memory chunk it returns to you, you are responsible for that.

If the memory pointed to by `newNode` *happens* to be all zeroes, your code might work, if not, it might crash, it is called *Undefined behavior*, different environment will behave differently, which explains why the guy in the tutorial and PaulRooney get the expected behavior and you don't.

Comment: Yes. Perfect. Thanks. Coming from Java, I assumed C just initializes things to null if they have never been manually initialized. I guess not. Head scratching thing was there was no error or anything. It compiled just fine. Just nothing showed up. Is that normal?

Comment: Modern compilers with issue useful diagnostics when told to do so with appropriate options such as `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`, but for this particular case, a classic bug, I don't think any compiler would help.  That's too bad, but now you know you must be very careful with `malloc`.